# Is there a specific ordering needed for classes in Peewee models?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, peewee

I'm currently trying to create an ORM model in Peewee for an application. However, I seem to be running into an issue when querying a specific model. After some debugging, I found out that it is whatever below a specific model, it's failing.

I've moved around models (with the given ForeignKeys still being in check), and for some odd reason, it's only what is below a specific class (User).

```py
def get_user(user_id):
    user = User.select().where(User.id==user_id).get()
    return user

class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    """A base model that will use our MySQL database"""
    class Meta:
        database = db


class User(BaseModel):
    id = pw.AutoField()
    steam_id = pw.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    name = pw.CharField(max_length=40)
    admin = pw.BooleanField(default=False)
    super_admin = pw.BooleanField()

#...
```

I expected to be able to query Season like every other model. However, this the peewee error I run into, when I try querying the User.id of 1 (i.e. `User.select().where(User.id==1).get()` or `get_user(1)`), I get an error returned with the value not even being inputted.

```sh
UserDoesNotExist: <Model: User> instance matching query does not exist:
SQL: SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`steam_id`, `t1`.`name`, `t1`.`admin`, `t1`.`super_admin` FROM `user` AS `t1` WHERE %s LIMIT %s OFFSET %s
Params: [False, 1, 0]
```

Does anyone have a clue as to why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message. It is telling you that the user with the given ID does not exist.

Peewee raises an exception if the call to `.get()` does not match any rows. If you want "get or None if not found" you can do a couple things. Wrap the call to .get() with a try / except, or use get_or_none().

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.get_or_none

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to this, but then why does `User.get(1)` return the proper value (user ID of 1), while the other `User.select().where(User.id==1).get()` returns nothing, with params `[False, 0, 1]`? I understand the 0 and 1 are for limit and offset, but it seems the `User.id==1` is evaluating as a boolean, and  sending in `False` instead of an expression to evaluate in the query. Is this correct? If so, why is it giving `False` as a param? But, I will definitely be using the get_or_none() since I did come across that after posting this question!

Answer (score -1):

Well I think I figured it out here. Instead of querying directly for the server ID, I just did a `User.get(1)` as that seems to do the trick. More reading shows there's a [get by id](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#selecting-a-single-record) as well.